# Stacked dot plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, stacked

I am interested in making a stacked dotplot like the one in link below in ggplot2.

[image]

The following was made using `dotPlot` function in `BHH2` package but does not have the coloring and faceting ease of `ggplot2`.

Comment: You're looking for `geom_dotplot`

Answer (score 5):

There is a `geom_dotplot` which create dotplots. Update your ggplot2 if you don't have it. It is a relatively recent addition.
See [this](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_dotplot.html) for examples.

Comment: I just saw this with Winston's post on ggplot2 google group.  Thanks its what I needed.